# Can we form two teams when there are few pairs which can't be in same team

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across a question in a company's interview test. The question is as follows.

There are N members we have to return if we can form two teams out of them there are M pairs of people who can't be in the same team. We have to return if we can form the team.

Comment: I understood that we have to use graphs but I couldn't go any further with the directed graph I created.

Comment: Why a directed graph?

Comment: Hey, I just figured it out, I've to basically check if this is a bipartite graph.

Comment: yes that seems to be right

Comment: I edited the title of the question. "Teams of 2" is very different from "two teams".

Comment: Run through the M pairs, assigning one of each pair to the first team and the other to the second team.  Assign the remaining people to the two teams after that.

Comment: Detect a cycle of length > 1 in the graph of incompatibilities ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès needs to be an odd-length cycle

Comment: @rossum this doesn't work. Take a hexagon. Take the pair (1,2). Assign 1 to team A and 2 to team B. Now take the pair (4,5). Assign 4 to team A and 5 to team B. What do you do with 3 and 6?

Comment: Assign 3 to one team and 6 to the other, or vice versa.  I don't see a problem, unless you have a heptagon and the teams have to be unequal.

Comment: @rossum 3 cannot be in team A because 4 is in team A, and it cannot be in team B because 2 is in team B.

Comment: Then you have a case where two teams are impossible to form.  Such cases are implied in the question.